# Fastest way of loading list of C# POCO objects in Cassandra using C# Client

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have ~80K list of C# POCO objects which I have read from a database. I need to load/insert these 80K POCO objects into Cassandra. I am using Datastax .NET Cassandra driver. Iterating through a for loop and inserting one by one takes forever. I also read that CQL Batches are not really meant for loading mass data. Is there a fast way of loading large number of objects into Cassandra?

Comment: Try execute async and a semaphore.